# How do I resolve linker library order problems?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I am trying to compile a C program that requires the use of several libraries. The problem is, the order the libraries are linked in causes the compilation to fail.

Is there anyway to get GCC to figure out the correct order, or for me to figure out the correct order without having to try every possibility?

```
mipsel-linux-gcc ffmpeg_mips_test.c -o ffmpeg_mips_test -Wall -v -I/ffmpegMIPS/includeffmpegMIPS/
                 -L/ffmpegMIPS/libffmpegMIPS/ -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lm -lpthread
```

The way I am doing it at the moment, is starting off with one, and then adding more libraries as the errors occur, however sometimes it feels like progress and then sometimes it just seems like I hit a dead end.

[edit]The compilation fails because of undefined references[/edit]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options

1) You can add additional calls to your library(s) that have dependencies

2) You can use the `--start-group / --end-group` options like so:

```
mipsel-linux-gcc ffmpeg_mips_test.c -o ffmpeg_mips_test -Wall -v -I/ffmpegMIPS/includeffmpegMIPS/
-L/ffmpegMIPS/libffmpegMIPS/ -Wl,--start-group -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -Wl,--end-group -lm -lpthread
```

Here is the `ld` manpage entry describing its use

> The specified archives are searched
>   repeatedly until no new undefined
>   references are created.  Normally, an
>   archive is searched only once in the
>   order that it is specified on the
>   command line.  If a symbol in that
>   archive is needed to resolve an
>   undefined symbol referred to by an
>   object in an archive that appears
>   later on the command line, the linker
>   would not be able to resolve that
>   reference.  By grouping the archives,
>   they all be searched repeatedly until
>   all possible references are resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `-lpthread` is deprecated. You should use `-pthread` and gcc will generate whatever options and libraries are needed for pthread support.

As for the others, putting them in the right order is merely a matter of understanding the dependencies between them. If `A` depends on `B`, `-lA` should appear before `-lB` on the command line. In your case, `-lm` is the system math library (which is only separate from the main libc for stupid legacy reasons) and does not depend on anything else, so it should always be at the end of the command line. `-lavutil` is a library of utility functions used by `ffmpeg` and its included libraries, so it should come after all of the other `ffmpeg` libraries. `-lswscale` is an image scaling library which the other libraries might need, so I would put it after `-lavformat` and `-lavcodec` but before `-lavutil` in case it needs functions from `-lavutil`.

Finally, in the `ffmpeg` world, codecs are considered fundamental and containers are considered a layer on top of them (rather the opposite of some frameworks), so `-lavformat` depends on `-lavcodec`. Thus the final order in your example should be:

```
-lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lm
```

And `-pthread` can go anywhere on the command line; it will usually cause gcc to put a hidden `-lpthread` at the end, but may do different things as necessary on different systems.